# Can an instance profile's condition reference EC2 instance's tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm trying to setup [an instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) for an EC2 instance that limits its access to a particular path within an S3 bucket, based on the `Name` tag of that EC2 instance. I've gotten a policy that's *close*, but still doesn't work.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "${aws:PrincipalTag/Name}/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Turns out that in the case of IAM roles for EC2, the principal is the role itself; not the EC2 instance. Is there any way to use the tags from the EC2 instance in the policy document?

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am in similar situation. I want to shape my instance profile to only access required resources based on tags

Comment: @user2574 No answer.